# highchart gradient color negative to positive bar horizontal

Tags: javascript, highcharts, colors, gradient

How to do this? In highchart ..

[horizontal bar with gradient.. red to gray for negative to positive values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13UC0.png)

Comment: You can set the individual bar's color based on the value in pre-processing. Without knowing more details it is hard to say what specifically you should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use already a Highcharts module which uses a color axis, you can use its tweenColors function to find the intermediate color.

As was mentioned, you have to loop through the data and set the point's color. If you don't want to use any other module, you need to find intermediate colors - answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173315/how-to-get-intermediate-colors-from-one-to-another).

```
var data = [100, 50, 20, -10],
  min = Math.min.apply(null, data),
  max = Math.max.apply(null, data),
  total = max - min,
  colorMin = new Highcharts.Color('rgb(255, 0, 0)'),
  colorMax = new Highcharts.Color('white'),
  tweenColors = Highcharts.ColorAxis.prototype.tweenColors;

 coloredData = data.map(value => {
   var pos = (value - min) / total;

   return {
     y: value,
     color: tweenColors(colorMin, colorMax, pos)
   };
 });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/oudktg0o/